# I have problem in apk upload at playstore its showing warning

Tags: android

I have already provided the permission      and also updated whats the new release notes then when its showing warning.Please give me the solution so that i can solve the warning problem.[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning, not error. And the warning is straight forward -- you added new permission. If user don't accept new permission, they will not upgrade to this version.

If your new permission is reasonable, user should accept and no worry on the warning message.

Comment: i am also saying its warning not error you just see my question.Actually, i have not updated new permission its old permission that  i had updated in my previous version then why this warning is showing in my new version,i am not getting it.